# Why does `FIELD(joined_table.column, NULL) = 0` not match when the `joined_table` is empty?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

`FIELD(NULL, NULL) = 0` yields results, also does `FIELD(table.column_is_null, NULL) = 0`, but not if the string to be compared comes from an empty join table column:

```
SELECT t.id, FIELD(tj.id, NULL) AS field_zero
FROM task t
    LEFT JOIN task tj ON FALSE
WHERE FIELD(tj.id, NULL) = 0
LIMIT 10
```

This query yields no results, but if i remove the `WHERE` clause `field_zero` is zero in all 10 rows:

```
SELECT t.id, FIELD(tj.id, NULL) AS field_zero
FROM task t
    LEFT JOIN task tj ON FALSE
LIMIT 10
```

According to the docs, `FIELD` "*Returns 0 if str is not found.*" (see: [MySQL 5.7 `FIELD` documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_field))

I searched for bugs of the `FIELD` function as well as special behaviour on websites documenting `FIELD` but couldn't find any mention of that issue.

#### Is this a known bug?

#### Or do i have a misunderstanding regarding the behaviour of `(LEFT) JOIN`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suspect this is in unknown bug in mysql.

When using `COALESCE` for the non-string from the empty join table, the query yields results:

```
SELECT t.id, FIELD(tj.id, NULL) AS field_zero
FROM task t
    LEFT JOIN task tj ON FALSE
WHERE FIELD(COALESCE(tj.id), NULL) = 0
LIMIT 10
```